# Video Indexer Logic App InvalidTemplate Error

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-video-indexer

I have created a Video Indexer with Logic Apps connector by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/logic-apps-connector-tutorial) Microsoft documentations bud in the Get Video Index I get this InvalidTemplate Error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, it was caused by missing query when you request the url of logic app trigger. The expression `triggerOutputs()['queries']['id']` mentioned in the document is used to get the `id` parameter in query of request. If you don't provide the `id` when you request the logic app trigger url, it will show this error message.

To solve this issue, you need to request the logic app trigger url with `id` in its query. Just append `&id=xxx` to the url and request it in postman or browser.

```
https://prod-21.eastasia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/6bfa4xxxxxxxx&sig=0ziso_T8xxxxxxxVNAidP6tiC22M_hhQH0&id=xxx
```

By the way, before request the url with `&id=xxx`, you need to set the trigger Method as `Get`.
[image]

Comment: Hello Hury Shen, I have added the Method GET, I still get the same error. although I got the header object as the result

Comment: @gwynncausing How did you trigger the logic app ? Click "Run" button on azure portal ? Or request it in postman or browser ?

Comment: I clicked "Run". Or I should use postman in this case?

Comment: @gwynncausing Yes, you need to copy the url and request it in postman or in browser with "Get" method.

Comment: Thanks Hury Shen! I just tried it on postman and it worked!